# Bootstrap Popover performance

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use the Bootstrap popover on a razor form. I have a list of things on the page that can be of any number of rows. One of the items in the row I want to have a popover show up when you mouse over it. (not my requirement)

I have the popover code working just fine except it is EXTREMELY slow. it there were 50 items in the list, it will lock up the browser for 30 seconds as it add the popover functionality to each of the items.

This is my reduced function to load each thing:

```
$("[name=pop]").each(function () {
        $(this).popover({
            trigger: "hover",
            html: true,
            animation: false,
            content: getContent($(this).prop("title"))
        });
    });
```

this is what is VERY SLOW. I don't think I've seen jquery do a looping of an each this bad before. Does the popover try to pre-populate the contents? I have it calling a function to get a partial view for the contents when the pop over is loading. It doesn't call my getContent so I assume it is not trying to pre-load.

Is there any way to speed this up or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What does `getContent` do ? Is the code inside that slow ?

Comment: What is `getContent()` doing? In isolation this works fine (http://jsfiddle.net/Lyo8uzg5/) so that must be the source of the problem.

Comment: Strange, the first time I tested to see if getContent was the problem it didn't react the way I thought.

It is indeed the slow part. 

So the question is, how can you get the popover to ONLY fetch the content when you actually hover over?

Answer (score 2):

Change the `title` attribute to `data-content` and use the below code.

```
$("[name=pop]").popover({
            trigger: "hover",
            html: true,
            animation: false
        });
```

**Update:**

To load contents dynamically, try something like this

```
$("[name=pop]").hover(function() {
   $(this).popover({
                trigger: "hover",
                html: true,
                animation: false,
                content: getContent($(this).prop("title"))
            }).popover('show');
});
```

Comment: how does that help me get the data I need to show dynamically? the title aspect is not the problem and I need to load content dynamically.

Comment: the most important thing is that in bs5 if we use lots of popovers, for example load them multiple times in modals and close, it will reduce the performance heavily, but now with this trick, it will improve the performance greatly, thank!